# Función asincrona Nodejs - optimización

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api, mongoose, async-await

quisiera saber si hay forma de optimizar el tiempo de respuesta de una función asíncrona la cual hace dos búsquedas anidadas en una API que estoy construyendo.

1.- Esta función va y consulta la tabla de productos y por Id de categoría

2.- Construyo mi objeto con los datos que me regresa la variable **productos**

3.- dentro de el loop de productos necesito agregarle información que traigo de otra tabla **getFilesByProductoId**

```
    let getCatalogos = async (categoria_id)=>{
       let productos = await getProductosByCategoriaId(categoria_id);

       let data = productos.map( async (item)=>{
        let obj_final={};
        obj_final._id = item._id;
        obj_final.producto =item.producto;
        obj_final.activo =item.activo;
        let fileInfo = await getFilesByProductoId(item._id).then((data)=> {return data}).catch(error=>{return error});
        obj_final.fileInfo = fileInfo;
        return data;
      });

    let finalData = await Promise.all(data);
    return finalData;
   }
```

- Promesa que regresa los registros de productos

```
let getProductosByCategoriaId = (categoria_id)=>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        CatProductos.find({ categoria_id: categoria_id })
        .then(success=>{
            resolve(success);
        }).catch(error=>{
            reject(error);
        });
    });
}
```

- Promesa que regresa los registros de documentos

```
let getFilesByProductoId = (producto_id) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        File.find({
            producto_id: producto_id
        }).then(success=>{
            resolve(success);
        }).catch(error=>{
            reject(error);
        });
    });
}
```

**Tiempo de respuesta** obteniendo la información de documentos: 3.11s

**Tiempo de respuesta** sin la información de documentos: 53ms

**Resultado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cual seria la mejor forma de hacer esto y con un mejor tiempo de respuesta???

Comment: Hola, he visto interesante tu pregunta, pero me choca un poco la vista al leer: *tabla* y que pongas la etiqueta de `mongoose`. Si estás trabajando con MongoDB, no son tablas las que consultas sino colecciones. Por otro lado, tu pregunta es sobre eficiencia. La misma dependerá del tipo de consulta que estás realizando. Si existe una referencia entre colecciones, y la misma está implementada en tu esquema de Mongoose, pordrías usar el método `populate`. Si por el contrario no hay referencias, lo más apropiado sería usar un proceso de agregación para obtener el resultado.

Comment: tu pregunta se basa en opiniones , puedes mejorar la respuesta desde una mejora a tu servidor a una migracion de base de datos incluso un cambio de codigo y/o consulta